# Ruby class/object/module diagram explanation

Tags: ruby, oop

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Class.html
"Classes, modules, and objects are interrelated. In the diagram that follows, the vertical arrows represent inheritance, and the parentheses meta-classes. All metaclasses are instances of the class `Class`."

```
                     +---------+             +-...
                     |         |             |
     BasicObject-----|-->(BasicObject)-------|-...
         ^           |         ^             |
         |           |         |             |
      Object---------|----->(Object)---------|-...
         ^           |         ^             |
         |           |         |             |
         +-------+   |         +--------+    |
         |       |   |         |        |    |
         |    Module-|---------|--->(Module)-|-...
         |       ^   |         |        ^    |
         |       |   |         |        |    |
         |     Class-|---------|---->(Class)-|-...
         |       ^   |         |        ^    |
         |       +---+         |        +----+
         |                     |
obj--->OtherClass---------->(OtherClass)-----------...
```

What is `obj`? What is `OtherClass`? What is horizontal arrow? What could be on the other side of the ... ?

"All metaclasses are instances of `Class`." Is that the only place where something is an instance of and also inherited from?

Comment: Oops. Fixed the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is obj?**

`obj` is an instance of `OtherClass`. You would get it by calling

```
obj = OtherClass.new
```

**What is OtherClass?**

`OtherClass` is any class not in the set of `Class`, `Module`, `Object`, and `BasicObject`. You could create one such class by writing

```
class OtherClass
end
```

though core library classes such as `String` and `Array` fit here as well.

**What is horizontal arrow?**

Besides the arrow from `obj` to `OtherClass`, each horizontal arrow represents the act of calling `.singleton_class`, which returns a one-off `Class` object also known as the metaclass.

**What could be on the other side of the "..."?**

If you'll notice, the entire structure on the right half of the chart is derived by calling `.singleton_class` to extract the metaclass from the left half of the chart. The "..."s on the far right represent a recursive continuation of that same pattern, i.e. calling `.singleton_class` on the metaclasses themselves, then calling `.singleton_class` on the metaclasses of the metaclasses, and so on.

***All metaclasses are instances of Class.* Is metaclass the only example of being an instance of what it inherits from?**

It's equally true that all classes are instances of `Class`. Any instance of any class is, by definition, an instance of what it inherits from.

The metaclass of `BasicObject`, curiously, is unique in that there is no other object whose class and superclass are the same. Some other interestingly self-referential objects include:

1) the `Object` class object

```
Object.is_a?(Object)
# => true

Object.class.superclass.superclass
# => Object
```

2) the `Class` class object

```
Class.is_a?(Class)
# => true

Class.class
# => Class
```

3) the `Module` class object

```
Module.is_a?(Module)
# => true

Module.class.superclass
# => Module
```

4) the `BasicObject` class object

```
BasicObject.is_a?(BasicObject)
# => true

BasicObject.class.superclass.superclass.superclass
# => BasicObject
```